# Java - send signal from Thread to Swing component

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, signals

I would like to ask, if I can run Thread and if some event happened, send signal and some swing components will catching signals.
Something like this:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
  String today = "???";

  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (today.equals("monday")) {
        // send signal
    }
  }
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
  // catching signals and if signal is catched change background color
}
```

EDIT:
I tried this, but it do not work.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("doInBackground");
            publish("doInBackgroundPublish");
            firePropertyChange("firePropertyChange1", "oldValue1", "newValue1");
            return "doInBackground return";
        }
        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            super.process(chunks);
            firePropertyChange("firePropertyChange2", "oldValue2", "newValue2");
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

}

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
public class SWListen implements PropertyChangeListener, Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("SWListen update");
    }
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("SWListen propertyChange");
    }
}
public MyPanel {
    addPropertyChangeListener(new SWListen());
}
```

}

Comment: [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Thank you.
I do not know If I understand well. SwingWorker is like a Thread when I need to run something in my Swing component?
But I need something different. I have got Thread that do something on background and when some event happend, I want inform component about the event.
Component will not start my Thread. My Thread start before MyPanel exists. MyThread and MyPanel are separated files (classes). And from MyThread I want to send signal to MyPanel1, MyPanel2, MyPanel3, ...

Comment: Then, from the `doInBackground` method, you call `publish`, passing the object you want sent to the EDT, then in the `process` method you will be supplied a `List` of objects which you can then update the UI with safely, as it's called from within the context of the EDT

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still a little confused. Where should I implement SwingWorker with doBackground and publish methods? In MyThread? And how to catch signal in MyPanel class?

Comment: `SwingWorker` has it's own threading capabilities. It will call `doInBackground` (at some point) after `execute` is called, this is when you're running off the EDT.  You call `publish` from within the `doInBackground` method when you want to send something to the EDT.  You use `process` to process that information within the EDT, this is when it's safe to notify your UI. This then comes down to a simple observer pattern. The question right now is both to broad (so many ways it "might" be done) and simplistic - Use a thread, use an observer pattern, sync the EDT

Comment: Thank you. But I have to do something very wrong. I do not know how to do. I edited my first post, what I tried, but It do not work and I do not know what else to do. Could you post code, how to do it?

Comment: `MyThread` isn't required  - or at least it doesn't need to wrap `SwingWorker`, it can just extend from `SwingWorker` directly

Comment: I give up. I really do not know how to send signal from MyThread to MyPanel and in MyPanel catch it and do something.... Thank you for your help and time, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SwingWorker` is a self contained "thread" (for argument sake), this means that it will create and launch it's own `Thread` from which `doInBackground` will be called.

`doInBackground` should then "do something" and call `publish` with the intermediate value (assuming your want to produce an overall value at the end, otherwise, it just generates a value)

At some point in the future `process` is called.  This method is called from within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within.

There are a number of ways you could then "notify" the UI of the changes, most will fall under the category of an "observer pattern".

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label);

            TickerWorker worker = new TickerWorker();
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println(evt.getPropertyName());
                    if ("counter".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        long value = (long) evt.getNewValue();
                        label.setText(Long.toString(value));
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class TickerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Long> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            long counter = 0;
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publish(++counter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Long> chunks) {
            // Since we're in the EDT, it's probably pointless do announce ALL the
            // values, we're probably only interested in the last one
            for (long value : chunks) {
                firePropertyChange("counter", value - 1, value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now, this notifies a single component, if you need to notify a number of components, then it becomes an order of magnitude more difficult.

You could have each component create it's own `SwingWorker`, which monitors some global monitor lock, allowing the "main" worker to trigger a `notifyAll`, which would then allow the "component workers" to publish some result ... but how do you get the value!?

At this point I'd probably just consider using some kind of [event bus](https://eventbus.org)